# Can't make Vue.js + TypeScript + RequireJS stack work after Vue.js 2.5 upgrade

Tags: typescript, vue.js, requirejs, vue-router

I have a project using Vue.js 2.4 + TypeScript + RequireJS stack that needs to upgrade to the latest Vue.js. Upgrade to Vue.js breaks it and I could not fix this after making changes per documentation.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Vue.js Scratchpad</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <script src="node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Vue.js Scratchpad</h1>

<div v-show="true" id="app" style="display: none">
  <input v-model="user" autofocus="true" placeholder="Enter any user name">
  <!--<button @click.prevent="onRenderComponent">Render</button>-->

  <p v-show="loading">Loading...</p>
  <router-view v-show="!loading" :user="user"
               @loading="onLoading" @success="onLoaded"
               @loading-error="onLoadingError"></router-view>
</div>

<script>
  requirejs.config({
    // By default load modules from `./`
    baseUrl: '.',

    /*
    By default, modules would be loaded from {module}.js files (filename = module).
    Specify {module} (or "{module}"): "{filepath_no_extension}" mapping if filename != module.
    Specify fall-backs ([filepath1, filepath2]) for minimized / normal version consumption pattern.
    */
    paths: {
      // All third-party libraries must be included here. Use path fall-backs for minimized libs.
      axios: "node_modules/axios/dist/axios.min",
      vue: "node_modules/vue/dist/vue.min",
      "vue-router": "node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.min"
    }
  });

  require(["app-pure-vue.js"]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

app-pure-vue.ts:

```
import * as Vue from "vue";
import * as VueRouter from "vue-router";
import { AxiosError } from "axios";

//region App components
import MessageComponent from "./messageComponent-pure-vue";
//endregion

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    component: MessageComponent
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
});

const appOptions = {
  router,
  data() {
    return {
      user: null,
      loading: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onLoading() {
      // @ts-ignore
      this.loading = true;
      console.log("Loading...");
    },

    onLoaded() {
      // @ts-ignore
      this.loading = false;
      console.log("Loaded.");
    },

    onLoadingError(error: AxiosError, serviceUrl: string) {
      // @ts-ignore
      this.loading = false;
      console.log("Loading error for", serviceUrl, error.response);
    }
  }
};

new Vue(appOptions).$mount("#app");
```

messageComponent-pure-vue.ts:

```
import * as Vue from "vue";
import * as VueRouter from "vue-router";
import { AxiosError } from "axios";

//region App components
import MessageComponent from "./messageComponent-pure-vue";
//endregion

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    component: MessageComponent
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
});

const appOptions = {
  router,
  data() {
    return {
      user: null,
      loading: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onLoading() {
      // @ts-ignore
      this.loading = true;
      console.log("Loading...");
    },

    onLoaded() {
      // @ts-ignore
      this.loading = false;
      console.log("Loaded.");
    },

    onLoadingError(error: AxiosError, serviceUrl: string) {
      // @ts-ignore
      this.loading = false;
      console.log("Loading error for", serviceUrl, error.response);
    }
  }
};

new Vue(appOptions).$mount("#app");
```

This example works fine. Now, to upgrade to `Vue.js` 2.5.0 + the latest `vue-router`, here are the required documented changes:

1. `package.json`: **update to `"vue": "~2.5.0"` + `"vue-router": "~3.1.5"`**
2. `*.ts`: `import * as Vue from "vue";` => **`import Vue from "vue";`**
3. `app-pure-vue.ts`: `import * as VueRouter from "vue-router";` => **`import VueRouter from "vue-router";`**

The code would compile, but blow up on `Vue.extend()` in `messageComponent-pure-vue.ts`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (messageComponent-pure-vue.ts:5)
```

Could you help me to fix this? The minimal reproducible example is available here: https://github.com/DKroot/Scratchpad/tree/master/Client_Side/Vue.js-2.5. The working 2.4 code is at https://github.com/DKroot/Scratchpad/tree/master/Client_Side/Vue.js-2.4.

What I did so far on this:

1. Isolated the issue to 2.5.0 upgrade
2. Carefully reviewed 2.5.0 release notes (https://github.com/vuejs/vue/releases/tag/v2.5.0) and the corresponding blog post (https://medium.com/the-vue-point/upcoming-typescript-changes-in-vue-2-5-e9bd7e2ecf08)
3. Reviewed changes in TypeScript declarations in 2.5.0. The exports are a bit too complex for me to figure out what the root cause might be.

Comment: ```Previously, we already recommend using ES-style imports (import Vue from ‘vue’) everywhere with “allowSyntheticDefaultImports”: true in tsconfig.json. The new typings will officially move to ES-style import/export syntax, so that config is no longer necessary, and users are required to use ES-style imports in all cases.``` So you need to use `import Vue from 'vue'`, as that's the official ES-style import sytnax

Comment: @Ohgodwhy This is exactly what I did with 2.5.0: 

import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";

This allows code to compile. It blows up at runtime though.

Comment: What version of `vue-template-compiler` do you have installed?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy None. All of the dependencies in this minimal example are listed in `package.json`.

Comment: Can you verify that the `vue-template-compiler` version in your `lock file` matches the installed `Vue` version?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I checked `package-lock.json`. `vue-template-compiler` is not there (I'm not using it).

Comment: I must have misunderstood. Are you not using vue in a runtime environment? If you are, go ahead and require it and pin it at the same version as your `vue` is.

Comment: The code above is a full running example, not requiring a build. The example stack is using 1) Vue, 2) TypeScript (compile-time) and 3) RequireJS. Additionally, it's using 4) vue-router and 5) axios, but #4 and #5 look immaterial to the problem. That's all.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for clearing that up. Sorry I couldn't have been more helpful.

Comment: You might set up a minimal Github repo which reproduces the error so we can properly figure out what's going on and help.

Comment: @Aer0 Done: https://github.com/DKroot/Scratchpad/tree/master/Client_Side/Vue.js-2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL; DR

Add these to the project:

```js
// vue-loader.ts
import * as AllVue from "Vue";
import Defaults from "Vue";

export const Vue = AllVue as unknown as Defaults;
export default Vue;
```

```js
// vue-router-loader.ts
import * as AllVueRouter from "Vue-router";
import Defaults from "Vue-router";

export const Vue = AllVueRouter as unknown as Defaults;
export default Vue;
```

configure RequireJS like this:

```js
paths: {
  Vue: "node_modules/vue/dist/vue.min",
  vue: "vue-loader",
  "Vue-router": "node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.min",
  "vue-router": "vue-router-loader"
}
```

### Explanation

The issue is caused by how TypeScript generates the JavaScript for an `amd` module with default exports as well as how RequireJS loads those default exports.

When you do:

```js
import Vue from "vue";

Vue.extend(...);
```

TypeScript translates it into:

```js
define(["require", "exports", "vue"], function (require, exports, vue_1) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    vue_1.default.extend(..);
});
```

Note that `.default` part? the issue is that RequireJS, sets `vue_1` to be the actual `default`, so `vue_1.default` ends up being `undefined` (hence your original error)

When you use the loaders above, you are re-exporting the `*` which is actually the default export as both the non-default export AND the default export. This is the code that is generated for the `vue-loader.ts`:

```js
define(["require", "exports", "Vue"], function (require, exports, AllVue) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    exports.Vue = AllVue; // <--- this resolves your problem
    exports.default = exports.Vue;
});
```

in order to use our loaders, we're "re-routing" the resolution. So if real code tries to require `vue` it will go to our loader, which will load `Vue`, which is the *real* Vue code.

### Recommendation

I guess the best way to avoid this issue is by ***not*** using RequireJS - if you don't need IE support, you can just do [native module loading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) or use Webpack

### Another possible solution

Look here: [Missing default export when using SystemJS or RequireJS makes Vue unusable with TypeScript](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6815)

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic! You helped a lot with TypeScript skills that go far beyond my level.

We do need IE 11 (at least) and did prototype Webpack, but decided against using it because the value-add was not high enough for the existing codebase, which uses RequireJS.

Comment: A small addition: this solution worked perfectly on Mac and Windows. On Linux TypeScript compiler paths have to be added otherwise `tsc` can't resolve imports from "Vue" because of file system case sensitivity. To fix:

`tsconfig.json`:
```
"compilerOptions": {
    // Base directory to resolve non-relative module names. This must be specified if `paths` is.
    "baseUrl": "node_modules",
    "paths": {
      // Mappings are relative to `baseUrl`
      "Vue": ["vue"],
      "Vue-router": ["vue-router"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR:

Try this instead:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
```

#### Explanation:

When a module is written this way:

```js
// module.ts
export function x() { ... }
export function y() { ... }
```

you would import it like so:

```js
import * as Module from "./module";
```

but when it is written like this:

```js
// module-with-default.ts
export default class Module {
  public static function x() { ... }
  public static function y() { ... }
}
```

you would import it like this:

```js
import Module from "./module-with-default";
```

in both cases you will be able to use it like this:

```js
Module.x();
Module.y();
```

#### Changes in Vue.js:

This is [how it is exported in v2.5.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/0948d999f2fddf9f90991956493f976273c5da1f/types/index.d.ts#L3):

```js
export default Vue
```

and this is [is how it is exported in v2.4.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/94512f3e8cee4030a1096121700ed49afab48073/types/index.d.ts#L37):

```js
export = Vue;
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! This site is special, and a place where we can make a difference. It's about paying it forward!

Comment: @DoronG This is exactly what I did in https://github.com/DKroot/Scratchpad/tree/master/Client_Side/Vue.js-2.5, but it blows up: see #2 and #3 in the original question.

Comment: @DoronG I realized that I probably should have posted the non-working 2.5 version rather than the working 2.4 + changes. Let me know how you want to handle this. I can clarify the question or just leave it be. I just would like to get the fix ultimately.

Comment: @DKroot I'll take a look at your repos

Comment: @DoronG Thanks in advance!

Comment: @DKroot Added another answer, but keeping this one as it is a valid answer to the TypeScript portion of the issue